# List *all* projects in google cloud resource manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to list all projects using the google cloud resource manager API but some projects seem to be hidden. Specifically projects that belong to google apps scripts that are container bound. In the google cloud developers console I can see these projects when I click on the project drop-down at the top of the page under the "recent" category, but they can't be filtered for in that pop-up and they don't show up in the cloud resource manager api "list" call. However, if I perform a "get" call with the ID of such a project I get a proper response with the info. What am I missing? (No, this is not a pagination issue.)

Ultimately I want to enable the big-query API for these google docs container bound projects and I'm using the resource manager to try and find these projects to get the IDs. Maybe there is a better path... this is a horrible maze!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because GCP now uses the concept of organizations to group projects.  Currently, projects created in GCP will fall under a given organization.  When an Apps Script is created though, it is not assigned an organization, likely because its created in G Suite, not GCP.  You should be able to verify this by going to console.cloud.google.com and selecting 'No organization' from the drop down.

If you have access to the Apps Script projects, you can do a get via another GCP API (such as the Billing API).